The $\mathbb{Z}_4$ and $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$ Graded Brauer Groups over $\mathbb{C}$
The $\mathbb{Z}_2$ graded Brauer group over complex number, denoted by Br$_{\mathbb{Z}_2}(\mathbb{C})$, classifies equivalence classes of $\mathbb{Z}_2$ graded central simple algebras over $\mathbb{C}$. These are algebras that are graded by $\mathbb{Z}_2$, have $\mathbb{C}$ as their graded center, and are simple in the sense that they have no proper graded ideals. We know that Br$_{\mathbb{Z}_2}(\mathbb{C}) \cong \mathbb{Z}_2$, where the identity element corresponds to the usual matrix algebra over $\mathbb{C}$, i.e., $M_n(\mathbb{C})$, and the nontrivial element corresponds to the matrix algebra whose entries take values in the Clifford algebra $Cl_1$.
I was wondering what the group structures of Br$_{\mathbb{Z}_4}(\mathbb{C})$ and Br$_{\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2}(\mathbb{C})$ are, and what kinds of algebras the non-trivial elements correspond to?
Some more background: For the $\mathbb{Z}_4$ graded case, the graded center is defined as follows: it is the subalgebra spanned by homogeneous elements $c$ such that
$ch = hc \omega^{\partial c \partial h}$ for all homogeneous $h$, where $\partial c$ is the grading of $c$ and $\omega$ is a fourth root of unity. For a $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$ graded algebra $A$, it is central if the only homogeneous element of $A$ such that for all homogeneous elements $x\in A$ such that $xa = \phi(x,a) ax$ for all homogeneous $a \in A$, are in $\mathbb{C}$, where $\phi$ is a bicharacter defined here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2267051/on-group-graded-algebras-and-brauer-groups
The Clifford $Cl_1=\mathbb{C}\oplus\mathbb{C}g$, with $g^2=±1$, $g$ is ungraded central

How do you define the graded  center? what is $Cl_1$ for you ?

For the $\mathbb{Z}_4$ graded case, the graded center is defined as follows: it is the subalgebra spanned by homogeneous elements $c$ such that
$ch = hc \omega^{\partial c \partial h}$ for all homogeneous $h$, where $\partial c$ is the grading of $c$ and $\omega$ is a fourth root of unity. For a $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$ graded algebra $A$, it is central if the only homogeneous element of $A$ such that for all homogeneous elements $x\in A$ such that $xa = \phi(x,a) ax$ for all homogeneous $a \in A$, are in $\mathbb{C}$, where $\phi$ is a bicharacter defined here:

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2267051/on-group-graded-algebras-and-brauer-groups
